# Inequality with logarithm, missing one zero

Tags: inequality, logarithms, convex-analysis

I have been asked by a friend to solve the following inequality. She is in her first year of a Physics university course. I am in my third of a Mathematics, so I don't know what this says about my skills... But here I am, asking for help.

$$ (3x-1)\ln x + x -1 \leq 0$$

Here is what I got:

If I call the left side $f(x)$, it is a $C^\infty$ function over $\mathbb{R}^+$. Its second derivative is always positive, so the function is convex. Therefore the solution of the above inequality must be a (closed) interval. Obviously $f(1)=0$, so $1$ is one end of said interval, but I can't find the other.

To note: proving that the solution is a closed interval is rather easy. The exercise specifically asks to find said interval, and implies that it can be done in an exact, analytic way (withut numerical approximations).

Comment: You will need a numerical method, one root is $1$ and the other $$0.1754198071$$

Comment: I can’t help but wonder if there is a typo. I think you’ll need a CAS of some sort to determine the left endpoint of the interval.

Comment: You can form the equation $(3x-1) \ln x + x- 1 =0$ to the equation $x^{3x-1}\text{e}^x=\text{e}$. Maybe this helps?

Comment: @Riccardo Orlando Just to be clear on the question, is this a natural log: $ln(x)$ or is it base 10: $log_{10}(x)$?

Comment: Edited. The original statement did not specify, but I've never seen them use $\log_10$ without specifying the base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have $$((3x-1)\ln{x}+x-1)''=\frac{3x+1}{x^2}>0,$$ which says that the  equation $$(3x-1)\ln{x}+x-1=0$$ has two roots maximum.

$1$ is a root and the second is $0.1754...$ and we got the answer:
$$(0.1754...,1).$$
We can not write an exact value of the second root in the elementary functions.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but did you use a CAS to determine the left endpoint? Or is there some trick?

Comment: @Clayton I used a calculator. It needs three minutes for this. For the first step I took $0.3$ and the rest is  $0.2$, $0.15$, $0.16$, $0.17$, $0.175$, $0.1755$ and $0.1754$

Comment: Fair enough! Given it is supposedly from a physics homework set, it sounds like a reasonable solution!